# Manually trigger a dropdown event using just plain javascript?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am trying to trigger a manual dropdown event in javascript. below is the function where I am working. I am stopping the first event that takes place and now i want to trigger a drop down event.

```
stopNavigationTriggerDropDown(event: any){
     event.stopImmediatePropagation();
     event.stopPropagation();
     event.preventDefault();

     //code that triggers manual dropdown event
}
```

now this is the html code:

```
 <tr (click)="goToPlan(plan)">
    <td>....</td>...
    <td>
       <div class="input-group">
           <button (click)="stopNavigationTriggerDropDown($event)" type="button" class="btnTransparent" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
               <i class="fa fa-ellipsis-h"></i>
               <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
           </button>
         <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
            <a class="dropdown-item" (click)="action(apl)">Go</a>
         </div>
        </div>
      </td> 
  </tr>
```

I can not use jQuery just pure JavaScript. I have searched online but many examples show jQuery, but I need it to be just pure JS. I thank you guys in advance!

Comment: Provide html code, and how is it actually being triggered.

Comment: @Timggwp it has been added

Comment: Did you try to call `click` function? `var btn = document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0];` and `btn.click()`?

Comment: Have you tried creating an event? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createEvent

Comment: @Timggwp I have tried that and I am still not able to trigger the dropdown event.

Comment: @RolDev does it work when you click it manually?

Comment: @Timggwp When I comment out the javascript it works as expected

Comment: @RolDev in that case, comment your code and add the code that I wrote above.

Comment: @Timggwp I have edited my post to include the outer tr element in the html. when that function is invoked the view is changed, I do not want the view changed when a user clicks this particular td element.

Comment: @RolDev I meant your js code

Comment: @Timggwp, I have done that, still doesn't appear.

Answer (score 0):

There are two main ways you can accomplish this.

1:  Fire button's click event:

```
var button = document.getElementsByClassName("example");
button.click()
```

2: Create and dispatch an event on the page (see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events)

```
var button = document.getElementsByClassName("example");
var btnEvent = new Event('click');
button.dispatchEvent(btnEvent);
```

Comment: when i tried 1 nothing is happening, dropdown is not appearing.

Comment: When you manually click the button with your mouse, does it fire as expected?